# Advice on DB Changes

Tags: oracle, database-design

### Requirement:

I'm required to prefix a couple of strings to the existing one.

I.e. The current way, the Accounts been recorded in AccountID field looks as

> "621230093VN00"

Under the new format it should look as

> "JKB-621230093VN00"

---

### Context:

The field named *AccountID*, being a type of Char(15) which is the
primary key of a Table named ***Account*** and the Same is referenced
to other Master tables such as ClientAccount and Transaction tables
such as Account Ledger, Payment, Receipts and Journals etc.

---

### Stats:

- Account Table and Clientaccount Table have 50K records each;
- AccountLedger have about 5 Million records;
- Payment, Receipts, and Journals have combined  1 Million records;

---

### Our Concerns and Thinking:

Why we went ahead in prefixing the field instead of creating it separately was to not mess with Structure and System which was performing very well and thinking that it had a minimal consequences which results in than creating it as a separate field.

---

### How we think to go about:

For such, I understand that I need to drop all foreign keys associated to the table, drop the primary key, Increase the length of the field and any fields associated to the table (foreign) and finally recreate the primary keys and foreign keys again.

I seek your advice on this matter to say what I'm needed to is correct and if not point out anything I might have missed or anything you think I should do prior to performing this task.

Comment: Take care of field size, because FK check the different size (your old key was 13 chars the new has 17 chars and your size is 15). If you change from 15 to 17 you must change all linked table but peraphs you must remove the f.k. constraints before

Comment: Thanks @JoeTaras! In conclusion, I have to drop all Foreign Keys and Primary Keys, Increase the length in all referenced tables (In this case I might be able to change the type as well from Char to VarChar), Re-create the Primary Keys and then Foreign Keys with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and finally update (add the prefix) to Account Table (Parent) and all Child table will get updated

Comment: @Hifni: Yes, seems the correct way ;)